# Cloudstack virtual router not starting

Tags: apache-cloudstack

Cloudstack virtual router always in stopped state, even though i have changed cpu speed to 1 ghz and ram to 512 mb. Both secondary storage vm and console proxy vm are running. Virtual router not starting due to which vm not running, vm goes into error state.